# FASTAPI - Trying to make a generic token_verifyer which can be used for all end points

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, fastapi, python-decorators

```py
async def get_verified_token(request: Request):
    headers = request.headers
    token = headers.get('authorization')
    if not token:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Authorization token is missing")
    try:
        user = auth.verify_id_token(token)
    except auth.InvalidIdTokenError:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Invalid ID token")
    except auth.RevokedIdTokenError:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Revoked ID token")
    except Exception:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Internal server error")
    return user
    
# Define the endpoint to validate the token
@authRouter.post("/get_user_with_token")
async def validate(request:Request,user = Depends(get_verified_token)):
    """ Use this endpoint to verify the token and get the user details """
    return JSONResponse(content={"user":user}, status_code=200)
```

At the moment, I am doing the above in FASTAPI, to verify the token when in the case that someone hits the `/get_user_with_token` end point - the token from firebase gets verified and a user is returned

I want to make this generic so that it works for any route in the future that I add, even those that do not have a request object (if it is possible)

```
@authRouter.get("/get_data")
async def get_data(getGoalsData: GetGoalsData, current_user = Depends(get_verified_token)):
    # Your protected endpoint logic here
    return {"message": "This is protected data"}
```

If I have a route like the above, I want the current_user to be stored with the verified token. (see in this case I dont have `reqeuest:Request`)

Can this be done? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Fastapi middleware](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/middleware/)

In your case it will look something like this:

```py
import time

from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()


@app.middleware("http")
async def add_proceverify_token(request: Request, call_next):
    user = await get_verified_token(request)
    response = await call_next(request)
    return response
```

Comment: This is great! thank you! 
also how can I add this middleware for every other endpoint other than `/login` or `/register`?

Comment: You can add middleware to the whole app, as an in example. Or you can group endpoints by api routes https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/#import-the-apirouter and add middleware to only some of them